# sql query at the opening of a form in access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm facing an issue at the opening of a form in an access database that i'm developping. The query is running without stopping. I have to manually stop it (so the action described below is not executed).
At the opening the form should execute this part of code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1 SET Field1 = Null WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Query2 WHERE Query2.Field2 = Table1.Field2 AND Query2.Field3 = 0 AND Query2.Field1 = Table1.Field1)"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End sub
```

In other words, i need to check in Query2 in which records Field3 = 0 and among these records, which ones have Field1 matching Field1 of Table1 and Field2 matching Field2 of Table1. When these records are identified, I want to set the value of the records of Field1 in Table1 to Null.

```
For example (i put in "code" aspect to have this part more readable, but it's not code, only an example)

Table1.Field1 | Table1.Field2
ABC             12345
DEF             67891

Query2.Field1 | Query2.Field2 | Query2.Field3
ABC             12345           5            --> this record is not selected
DEF             12345           0            --> this record is not selected
DEF             67891           0            --> this record is selected and value of DEF in Table1 is deleted (Null)
```

Do you see any errors? Do you see any way to do that? i dont' know a lot about sql.
I hope it's clear enough...

Thanks,
Diane

Comment: How many rows are there in those tables (roughly)?

Comment: Looks like this is performance issue. Try the same on tables with small quantity of rows, if it works, first of all check if all table fields, used in `WHERE` and `JOIN` in all queries are indexed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i've like 2000 records in each. i've checked the index, one field was not indexed. i've tried with few records, it works. is there a better way do perform this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i would try is to change

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Query2 WHERE Query2.Field2
```

to

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Query2 WHERE Query2.Field2
```

While in most database engines there is no difference between the two, in Access it might make a difference.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Since that didn't help much, the next thing I would try is:

```
UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN Query2 ON Query2.Field2 = Table1.Field2 AND Query2.Field3 = 0 AND Query2.Field1 = Table1.Field1
SET Table1.Field1 = Null;
```

Please make sure you run this against a test database first.

HTH.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've tested this, and didn't see any improvement, still veryyyy long. any other idea?

Comment: Edited, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, i've finally done it in a different way, i'm not a programmer so perhaps it's not very clean but it works well for my purpose :-)

First i've modified a bit the query2 to limit to 2 conditions
Then i export the data of the query in a new table
Then i delete all records that i'm not interested in
Then i update the table1 using the remaining records (finally very few, so the query is quick). More steps but much quicker...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Append data of query2 to table2_temp
DoCmd.OpenQuery "query2"

'Delete some records in table table2_temp 
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM table2_temp WHERE table2_temp.field3 <> 0"

'Delete value in field1 and field2 of table1 where field2 exists in table2_temp
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE table1 SET field1 = Null WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2_temp WHERE table2_temp.field3 = table1.field2)"


'Empty the temp table
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM table2_temp"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```